# Как установить pytorch на raspberry pi c пайтоном 3.9

Tags: raspberry-pi, pytorch, raspbian

Может я путаю, но сейчас по умолчанию при загрузке raspbian, в аpt идёт только python3.9, и при этом там нету pytorch, я пробовал искать .whl файлы, но все они используются с python 3.7. Есть какой-то другой способ для установки pytroch на apt python3.9?
при
`pip install  pytorch`
выдаёт

````
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached pytorch-1.0.2.tar.gz (689 bytes)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Building wheel for pytorch (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-r3zk43_c/pytorch_0c302433dfe8495a9a6e0130a009c86b/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          raise Exception(message)
      Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytorch, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects ```
````

Comment: Pytorch через pip устанавливается, а не через apt. Или я не понял сути вопроса?

Comment: согласно информации на офф сайте `PyTorch only supports Python 3.8-3.11`, на Raspberry версия 3.9.2. Поэтому устанавливать командой `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio`

Comment: pip3.9 install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение для всех версий пайтона -- https://github.com/KumaTea/pytorch-arm/releases/tag/v1.8.1 , вместо названия модуля, нужно указать полный путь к файлу, при установке